К врачу или ко врачу?
Как правильно - к врачу или ко врачу?  Или можно и так, и так?

Этот вопрос похож на: К дню или КО дню?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Возможно, КО может указывать на какого-то особого врача.

Как правильно: к врачу или ко врачу?
Правильно: к врачу. Я никогда не скажу ко врачу. Зачем? Так никто не говорит, я не слышала. Произношение кажется мне диалектным.
ОТВЕТ

Такие вопросы неоднократно обсуждались на форуме, также назывались причины возможного колебания:

Предлоги "ко" и "к" Какой предлог выбрать: к или ко?

Прежде всего это связано с историей языка. Вариант КО соответствует историческому КЪ с редуцированным гласным Ъ, который в дальнейшем или отсутствовал, или произносился как обычный гласный О (сравнить: сон — сна).

Звук О остался в тех сочетаниях, где был необходим для удобства произношения, а также в устойчивых сочетаниях. Традиция также оказывает влияние. Иногда закономерность фонетической нестыковки определить достаточно сложно, например: ко мне, ко всему, но: к встрече. Соответственно, трудно предложить конкретное правило.

Фонетика в сочетании к врачу удобна для произношения (там есть сонорный согласный Р), к устойчивым сочетаниям сложно отнести, тогда приходится ориентироваться на традиционное литературное произношение.


Статья: «К врачу» или «КО врачу»: как должен говорить грамотный человек?
Все же грамотным назван вариант к врачу. Это ответ соответствует Письмовнику.

Почему говорят: ко мне, но к тебе, к нам, к вам, но ко всему, ко оному, ко многому, но к малому?)

Это влияние фонетики, нужно знать способ и место образования согласных звуков. Предлог КО используется, если стечение согласных неудобно для произношения. Ко мне - КМН, К и Н смычные зубные, но их разделяет губно-губный М. Ко всему - КВС.  Все звуки разные:  К зубный смычной, В - губно-зубный, С  - зубный щелевой. Ко многому - КМН. Трудные комбинации, поэтому желательно их разделить гласным.

Немного поспорю, с одной стороны да, но с другой есть же масса слов, которые упорно к, и очень редко ко, несмотря на МНение, ВСадник(и). Хотя, некоторые случаи мне кажутся лучше звучат как КО: "Образцовым искусства рассадником, А теперь управленья забота Перешла почему-то ко всадникам." или "но удивление его относилось еще боле к коню, чем ко всаднику."

Мне кажется буква О добавляет обстоятельственности, в отличие от К, который предлог дополнения, а не обстоятельства.

То есть вроде: он уставился на коня и его нисколько не смущало, какое благородное лицо восседало на коне. *Там пропущено:" Когда управляющим театрами назначили вместо пехотного офицера Пчельникова кавалериста Теляковского, Михаил Провыч пустил следующее четверостишие: Управляла когда-то пехота Образцовым искусства рассадником, А теперь управленья забота Перешла почему-то ко всадникам." Тут просто игра слов, пехота - это не совсем пехота, а всадники - это не совсем всадники, вроде юмор, поэтому тут нетипичное КО указывающее на это, лишающее "всадников" конкретизации, не всадники, а "всадники".

Прямого запрета на КО/К нет, в некоторых случаях допускаются оба варианта. В частности, размер стиха влияет в  вашем примере. Но КВС вообще неудобно для произношения. А вот насчет дополнения/обстоятельства не слышала, скорее это ваша оригинальная мысль) А может, и другие какие факторы действуют, которые мы не замечаем. Намеренный диалектизм может быть.

Ну вот употребимость к мнению/ко мнению, к всаднику/ко всаднику - 10 к 1. Но этот один про всадников прекрасно ложиться, а другие на К прекрасно звучат. Можно ещё какие-то слова на ВС проверить, на МН слов почти нет, только однокоренные МНОГО+что-то, многоножка. К многоножке, конечно, не ко многоножке.

Я полагаю так. Нужно четко знать норму, когда она единственная. А если допускаются два варианта, то чувство языка подскажет) А так интуицию трудно просчитать, это как интуитивно определить порядок слов в предложении.  Анализ на двух листах не поместится, а все равно никого однозначно не убедишь, в том числе себя. Интуиция свыше нам дана, замена логике она)

Нормативным вариантом принято считать "к врачу". "Ко" характерно для возвышенной речи и для устойчивых выражений. Однако оно употребляется при стыке большого количества согласных для удобства произношения, что справедливо в вашем случае. Кроме того, "ко врачу" — обиходное выражение, и вы вполне могли его слышать от многих людей. А передача в литературной речи именно живого, а не письменного языка является одной из важнейших задач для авторов. Так что если речь о художественном тексте, то это более чем оправдано.
